# Android Room concurrent reads with Coroutines

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Room with coroutines to store/retrieve data. From another post I saw that you could technically have unlimited number of retrievals from the database at the same time. Currently, I am working with a very large dataset that I want to retrieve. This is on the order of 10,000,000 rows. I split this up into smaller reads say by 4 (2,500,000), that all occur in parallel. This decreases my retrieval time by 30-40% which is what I want (this is relative to a single DB read). What bothers me is that when I increase this split value past 4, it actually slows down. I would think adding more parallel coroutines would keep splitting the time down.

I verified that all coroutines that are working in parallel are all unique threads so they are not clashing that way.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I was thinking maybe Room/SQL has a limit of the number of concurrent connections, however this should not be the case based on (5) in this link:

[SQlite Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand the coroutines concept a little. Coroutines are called light-weight threads, actually the number of used threads depends on the selected Dispatcher. For example the maximum number of threads of the [Default](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) dispatcher is equal to the number of CPU cores, but is at least two. It would be wasteful to create a separate thread for each coroutine and it contradicts one of the main ideas of coroutines - app threads consumption optimization. See [Coroutine context and dispatchers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html) for more details.